# linux find command match only exact match?

Tags: linux, find, tcl

A while ago I created a TCL script to compress automatically generated files into archives with a very specific naming convention. However, I have recently found a bug where, if a file has a name that contains the full string of another archive it will flag it as a copy.

I am using:

```
set stat [ exec find -name $combo | sort -r ]

set foo true
foreach m $stat {
    if { $foo } {
        set foo false

    } else {

        set bar [ string trimleft $m ./]
        set tmp "OLD_"
        set tmp $tmp$bar                
        exec mv $bar $tmp
    }
}
```

However, the issue I am seeing is if I have two archives:

```
12345_abcd_download
12345_abcd_download_again
```

The find function will return both. Is there a way to make it only return them if it's lexicographical equivalent?

Comment: It must have something to do with your $combo - maybe that contains a `*`. Try, on the command line, `find . -name "12345_abcd_download" -print`. This will *not* find your `12345_abcd_download_again` file.

Comment: Well don't I feel silly now.

Comment: Now that your problem is solved, may I suggest to forget about variable **foo** and do this: `foreach m [lrange $stat 1 end] {` -- That should eliminate the first item from the list.

Comment: Sorry I took such a long time to reply, but thanks for the tip with lrange! I didn't know that was possible!